# Bootstrap Popover: iOS Safari strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking through the Twitter Bootstrap documentation, and I'm interested in implementing a dismissible popover when a button is clicked. Here is the example from bootstrap's docs:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click

When I press the "Dismissible Popover" button from my OS X Safari browser it works fine. But when I access the same link above from iOS Safari, the button does not work. That is, the popover is not dismissed on click.

Why is this button not working with iOS Safari?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626171/bootstrap-popover-dismiss-on-click-works-fine-in-desktop-browser-but-not-in-mob?rq=1? There is a potential workaround for being unable to dismiss a popup there.

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to is using the `data-trigger="focus"` attribute. Try changing it to `data-trigger="click"`.

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

Comment: I did, but then it would not do what i want with it. The way i'd want it to work is when a user taps anywhere on their iOS safari screen, the popup will dismiss.

Comment: add `tabindex="0"` (and increment as needed) and then `data-trigger="focus"` should work. From the docs "For proper cross-browser and cross-platform behavior, you must use the <a> tag, not the <button> tag, and you also must include a tabindex attribute." See [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/)